# Display legend items in two columns highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

In highcharts is it possible to display the legend in two columns, stacked vertically?

I'm trying to work out the best way of displaying the legend items, at the moment we have the legend items all stacked on top of each other.

There will be a maximum of 4 series on the chart.

I'm not really sure how to approach this, I see the option of useHTML but then I can't seem to find any examples of what to do with the HTML.

http://jsbin.com/oyicuc/9/edit

Any advice would be very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried to use itemWidth parameter?

Please take look at

http://jsfiddle.net/B9L2b/1266/

```
 legend: {
    width: 200,
    itemWidth: 100
},
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.itemWidth

EDIT:

http://jsbin.com/oyicuc/31/

```
width:600,
        itemWidth:300,
        itemStyle: {
          width:280
        }
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#legend.itemStyle

Comment: hmmm, this doesn't seem to work when I try it with the jsbin in my question, does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
function renderElements() {
      if (this.legend) {
       this.legend.destroy();
      }
      //distance between 2 elements
      let itemDistance = this.legend.options.itemDistance;
      //the biggest element
      let maxItemWidth = this.legend.maxItemWidth;
      //make the width of the legend in the size of 2 largest elements + 
      //distance  
      let nextLegendWidth = (maxItemWidth * 2) + itemDistance;
      //container width
      let boxWidth = this.plotBox.width;
      //if the length of the 2 largest elements + the distance between them 
      //is less than the width of           container, we make 1 row, else 
      //set legend width 2 max elements + distance between
    if (boxWidth < nextLegendWidth) {
     this.legend.options.width = maxItemWidth;
    } else {
     this.legend.options.width = nextLegendWidth;
  }

  this.render()   
}

chart: {
    events: {
      load: renderElements,
      redraw: renderElements
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jecrovb7/38/

Comment: Awesome, exactly what we needed!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the "labelFormater" of the legend.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter

Then you could create a table and arrange the legend text as you wnat.

Have a look at the example on the documentation page.

Comment: how would you go about getting the entire legend into a table though? from what i can see this just wraps the individual legend items?