# how to add table in the legend section of the highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to be able to add a table right below the chart (possible in the legend section). I have a cpu chart but I need to be able to show if the threshold was breached and when.

Possibly in legend section, I need to be able call another series data (this is diffent that the chart data) and create table out of it.

This is what I have to create the cpu charts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

//$(function() {
function db_cpu() {

var  timeout;
    $.getJSON('db_cpu.php', function(data) {

        // Create a timer

        // Create the chart
        $('#db_cpu_div').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                borderColor: '#98AFC7',
                borderRadius: 20,
                borderWidth: 1,
                events: {
                    load: function(chart) {
                        this.setTitle(null, {

                        });
                    }
                },
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            exporting: {
            enabled: true
        },
        legend: {
                enabled: true
                },


});


    });
    timeout = setTimeout(db_cpu, 300000);

    }
    db_cpu();
});
```

Is it possible to create another function in the legend section to make another json call to a php file to get another series and dispaly this data in table format?

Table will be something like this:

```
Threshold Breached (as the title)
Date   Value
6/27/2013 12:00:00  96
6/29/2013 03:00:00  90
7/01/2013 09:00:00  75
7/05/2013 13:00:00  80
```

I need this area to be expandable/retractable with a + and - signs

Comment: Did you try setting width and height to get it in table format?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473996/display-legend-items-in-two-columns-highcharts this might help you.

Comment: Take look at the article http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$add-data-table which introudeces how to add table inside chart.