# How to group the legend together in Highcharts Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

[image: This is the output I am getting]

Hello ,the above is image which I m getting it as output but I want the output   to look like the below image , that is all the veg in one column and all the fruit in one column and so on. How can I achieve it ?
Thank you :)
[image]

Comment: What do you mean, can you provide your expected O/P. and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Hey @AkhilAravind , I have edited the question , please have a look at the output . Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @blessy julie, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4887/

Comment: Hey @ppotaczek , thanks for the example , but using the width , I m getting everything in one column , https://jsfiddle.net/pbe87mq0/18/

Comment: @blessy julie - please adapt the `width` to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ppotaczek !!! It did work !!! Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Highcharts Stacked and grouped column charts.

It allows you to set custom columns in different categories with data grouping:

[image: preview of the chart]

Here, the left column of each series is for the `vegetables` and the left is for the `fruits`.

Here's what your data will look like:

```js
  series: [{
    name: 'Tomato',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2, 3, 5],
    stack: 'veg'
  }, {
    name: 'Potato',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 7, 2],
    stack: 'veg'
  }, {
    name: 'Onion',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 1, 4],
    stack: 'veg'
  }, {
    name: 'Apple',
    data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 8, 1],
    stack: 'fruit'
  }, {
    name: 'Banana',
    data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5],
    stack: 'fruit'
  }, {
    name: 'Orange',
    data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
    stack: 'fruit'
  }]
```

**[Working demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/maximelafarie/9a7j46fr/1/)**.

**EDITED ANSWER:**

Your question seems to be a duplicate of "[Display legend items in two columns highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15473996/display-legend-items-in-two-columns-highcharts)".

So you can add to your chart's config:

```js
  legend: {
    width: 400,
    itemWidth: 200
  },
```

This will split the legend in two separated columns:

[image: splited legend preview]

Comment: How come this get upvoted, since the question is about grouping the legend :)

Comment: Hey @Maxime Lafarie , I have edited the question can u please have a look over the output which I would like to have . Thank you :)

Comment: @AkhilAravind the question wasn't edited by `blessy julie` so I'll edit my answer stay cool ;)

Comment: @blessyjulie I edited my answer so now it may fit your needs ;)

Comment: Thanks @MaximeLafarie !!! It did work :)